anchor_spl token_group_initialize invalid instruction
I'm receiving invalid instruction when calling token_group_intialize from the anchor_spl crate, I have followed this similar post but still no solution. Full code below.
    
    use anchor_spl::token_interface::{token_group_initialize,TokenGroupInitialize,Token2022,token_metadata_initialize, Mint, TokenMetadataInitialize};
    
    
    
    use crate::state::company::Company;
    use crate::utils::update_account_lamports_to_minimum_balance;
    pub fn create_collection(
        ctx: Context<CreateCollection>,
        name: String,
        symbol: String,
        uri: String,
        max_size: u32,
    ) -> Result<()> {
     
        msg!("Creating collection!");
        ctx.accounts.initialize_token_metadata(name.clone(), symbol.clone(), uri.clone(), ctx.bumps.company)?;
     
        msg!("Token metadata initialized!");
        ctx.accounts.mint_account.reload()?;
    
        msg!("Initializing group");
        ctx.accounts.initialize_group(max_size,  ctx.bumps.company)?;
        msg!("Group initialized!");
        ctx.accounts.mint_account.reload()?;
        msg!("Updating account lamports to minimum balance");
       update_account_lamports_to_minimum_balance(
            ctx.accounts.mint_account.to_account_info(),
            ctx.accounts.payer.to_account_info(),
            ctx.accounts.system_program.to_account_info(),
        )?;
    
        Ok(())
    }
    #[derive(Accounts)]
    #[instruction(name: String)]
    pub struct CreateCollection<'info> {
        #[account(mut)]
        pub payer: Signer<'info>,
        #[account(
            mut,
            seeds = [b"company", payer.key().as_ref()],
            bump,
        )]
        pub company: Account<'info, Company>,
    
        #[account(
            init,
            payer = payer,
            seeds = [b"mint", company.key().as_ref(), name.as_bytes()],
            mint::token_program = token_program,
            mint::decimals = 0,
            mint::authority = company,
            mint::freeze_authority = company,
            extensions::metadata_pointer::authority = company,
            extensions::metadata_pointer::metadata_address = mint_account,
            extensions::group_pointer::authority = company,
            extensions::group_pointer::group_address = mint_account,
            extensions::permanent_delegate::delegate = nft_authority,
            // extensions::transfer_hook::authority = nft_authority,
            // extensions::transfer_hook::program_id = crate::ID,
            bump
            
        )]
        pub mint_account: Box<InterfaceAccount<'info, Mint>>,
    
        #[account(
            init_if_needed,
            //don't do this
            payer = payer,
            space = 8 + NftAuthority::INIT_SPACE,
            seeds = [b"nft_authority".as_ref()],
            bump,
        )]
        pub nft_authority: Account<'info, NftAuthority>,
    
        pub rent: Sysvar<'info, Rent>,
    
        pub token_program: Program<'info, Token2022>,
        pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
       
      
    }
    
    impl<'info> CreateCollection<'info> {
        fn initialize_token_metadata(
            &self,
            name: String,
            symbol: String,
            uri: String,
            bump: u8
        ) -> ProgramResult {
    
             let payer_binding = self.payer.key();
            let seeds = &[b"company",payer_binding.as_ref(),&[bump]];
            let signer = [&seeds[..]];
            let cpi_accounts = TokenMetadataInitialize {
                token_program_id: self.token_program.to_account_info(),
                mint: self.mint_account.to_account_info(),
                metadata: self.mint_account.to_account_info(), // metadata account is the mint, since data is stored in mint
                mint_authority: self.company.to_account_info(),
                update_authority: self.company.to_account_info(),
            };
            let cpi_ctx = CpiContext::new_with_signer(self.token_program.to_account_info(), cpi_accounts,&signer);
            token_metadata_initialize(cpi_ctx, name, symbol, uri)?;
            Ok(())
        }
    
        fn initialize_group( &self, max_size:u32, bump: u8) -> ProgramResult {
    
            let payer_binding = self.payer.key();
            let seeds = &[b"company",payer_binding.as_ref(),&[bump]];
            let signer = [&seeds[..]];
    
            token_group_initialize(
                CpiContext::new_with_signer(
                    self.token_program.to_account_info(),
                    TokenGroupInitialize {
                        token_program_id: self.token_program.to_account_info(),
                        group: self.mint_account.to_account_info(),
                        mint: self.mint_account.to_account_info(),
                        mint_authority: self.company.to_account_info(),
                    },&signer
                ),
                Some(self.company.key()), // update_authority
                max_size,                             // max_size
            )?;
    
            Ok(())
        }
    }
    
    #[account]
    #[derive(InitSpace)]
    pub struct NftAuthority {
        pub bump: u8,
    }

Error:
    Message: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 0: custom program error: 0xc.
    Logs:
    [
      "Program TokenzQdBNbLqP5VEhdkAS6EPFLC1PHnBqCXEpPxuEb consumed 9889 of 154684 compute units",
      "Program TokenzQdBNbLqP5VEhdkAS6EPFLC1PHnBqCXEpPxuEb success",
      "Program log: Token metadata initialized!",
      "Program log: Initializing group",
      "Program TokenzQdBNbLqP5VEhdkAS6EPFLC1PHnBqCXEpPxuEb invoke [2]",
      "Program log: Error: Invalid instruction",
      "Program TokenzQdBNbLqP5VEhdkAS6EPFLC1PHnBqCXEpPxuEb consumed 833 of 140935 compute units",
      "Program TokenzQdBNbLqP5VEhdkAS6EPFLC1PHnBqCXEpPxuEb failed: custom program error: 0xc",
      "Program 2zG2G696WnzNVPzP7MCPgQ5fJZnhYDsR71UUHCB4fdfW consumed 59898 of 200000 compute units",
      "Program 2zG2G696WnzNVPzP7MCPgQ5fJZnhYDsR71UUHCB4fdfW failed: custom program error: 0xc"
    ].
    Catch the `SendTransactionError` and call `getLogs()` on it for full details.
          at Connection.sendEncodedTransaction (node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/connection.ts:5927:13)
          at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
          at Connection.sendRawTransaction (node_modules/@solana/web3.js/src/connection.ts:5883:20)
          at sendAndConfirmRawTransaction (node_modules/@coral-xyz/anchor/src/provider.ts:373:21)
          at AnchorProvider.sendAndConfirm (node_modules/@coral-xyz/anchor/src/provider.ts:163:14)
          at MethodsBuilder.rpc [as _rpcFn] (node_modules/@coral-xyz/anchor/src/program/namespace/rpc.ts:29:16)


The token group extension in token-2022 has not been deployed yet. If you want to use it, you'll need to build token-2022 yourself and include it in your test validator, ie:
$ git clone https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library.git
$ cd solana-program-library/token/program-2022
$ cargo build-sbf
$ solana-test-validator --bpf-program TokenzQdBNbLqP5VEhdkAS6EPFLC1PHnBqCXEpPxuEb \
  ../../target/deploy/spl_token_2022.so


That worked! Thanks @Jon C
I was able to find the status of group extension here https://github.com/orgs/solana-labs/projects/34
